# How can I add/cut face into an inside face of a cube?

Tags: knife-tool

I'm unable to cut a face into an inside face of a cube as it's not really accessible, can't move the view there. I was trying to zoom in and navigate inside of the cube in order to use a plane to knife project. This did not work as zooming in prevented me to see where I was.

How to do it?

[image: cube]

Comment: Orthographic mode will not allow you to zoom into inside of an object. Either hide any other faces obscuring visibility of the related one or enter Perspective mode (and even then hiding might be the best way)

Comment: Hiding worked! Thanks, it'd be worth an answer.